# error with sending object to another activity

Tags: java, android, class

my app always crashes when i send an object to the main activity. I want it so the main activity displays a String from my class but everytime I press the row in the second activity and go back to the main activity the app crashes can someone please help me to fix this, thanks.

**my class below**

```
public class Ship implements Serializable {


public String test()
{
    String s = "Hello Android!";
    return s;
}
```

}

**Second Activity**

```
 hangarList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


           Intent sendListEvents = new Intent();
           if(position == 1)
           {

               Ship test = new Ship();
               sendListEvents.putExtra("ship1", test);

           }
            //insert position events ^^^
            setResult(RESULT_OK, sendListEvents);


 }
    });
```

**Main Activity below**

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == result) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Intent getData = getIntent();
            Ship ship1 = (Ship) getData.getSerializableExtra("ship1");
            String s = ship1.test();
            test.setText(s);

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: what row you click? your intent contains extra only when you click the second row. moreover, you put "ship1" and get "Ship1". feel the difference

Comment: Provide stack trace from your [`LogCat`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

Comment: @AlexanderZhak  i changed the the Ship1 to ship1 but still is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
Intent getData = getIntent();
Ship ship1 = (Ship) getData.getSerializableExtra("Ship1");
```

With this:

```
Ship ship1 = (Ship) data.getSerializableExtra("ship1");
```

Also, I recommend making "ship1" a final static constant value to avoid typos when trying to reference it. If you need to know the position in the list that was clicked, you can pass that as another intent extra.